# Taking the dual of this two-dimensional linear program

Tags: linear-programming

I have just begun learning about LP duality and how to take the dual of an LP, however this question I've come across has me stumped:

\begin{alignat}{4}
\max  \quad & \rlap{\sum_{j=1}^{m} \sum_{i=1}^{n}v_{ij}x_{ij}} \\
\text{s.t. } \quad & \sum_{j=1}^{m}x_{ij} &=1 & \quad\forall\, i\in \{1,...n\} \\
& \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{ij} &\leq b & \quad\forall\, j\in \{1,...m\},\\
\text{where } \quad&x_{ij} \ge 0 \\
& \rlap{v_{ij} \text{ are constants}.}
\end{alignat}

Comment: And why are you stumped?

Comment: So i've split the first constraint into $\\
\sum_{j=1}^{m}x_{ij} \leq1 \space\forall\space i\in \{1,...n\}\\ -\sum_{j=1}^{m}x_{ij} \leq-1 \space\forall\space i\in \{1,...n\}\\$  I'm just having trouble visualising the matrix of the constraints and objective values, because of the weird dimensionality.

Comment: Think of $x$ as one long vector in $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$ and write the cost & constraints in terms of that vector. It depends on which 'standard' form you take.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189)
I have tried to improve the readability of your question by improving
[$\rm \LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27756/290189). It is
possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.
Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: Okay thanks, that does seem like a good idea haha, will try it now.